# making my spanish as neutral as possible(avoid subjuntivo) at the cost of not sounding like native?

Tags: subjuntivo

what if my goal in Spanish is to speak in clear terms and rather in simple sentences? I intentionally want to avoid subjuntivo as a hard topic and unecessary complexity.

but can i still sound as c1-b2 if i avoid subjuntivo as much as possible? hope this makes sense.

Comment: No creo que sea una buena idea. No lo recomiendo

Comment: The irony is that in asking your question, you have used the subjunctive in English.

Comment: You can't speak Spanish without the subjunctive.

Comment: This question reminds me of an anecdote related to me by my Spanish teacher: a new student who wanted to learn quickly and wondered if not bothering to learn any verbs would be the way to go

Answer (score 3):

According to the text on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages)

For B2 you need to be able to, amongst other things

> understand the main ideas of complex text on both concrete and abstract topics, including technical discussions in their field of specialisation.

For C1

> Can understand a wide range of demanding, longer clauses and recognise implicit meaning

It is hard to see how you can reach either of those levels without using the subjunctive. It is not clear to me if you can even reach B1 but that is not what you asked.

Answer (score 3):

Subjunctive is introduced in [B1](https://cvc.cervantes.es/ensenanza/biblioteca_ele/plan_curricular/niveles/02_gramatica_inventario_b1-b2.htm#p92t). Not only you will not sound native, you won't even sound B1.

You will be understood if you don't use the subjunctive at B1 level:

- "No creo que él **esté** cansado" = "I don't think he is tired"
- "No creo que él **está** cansado" (wrong but understandable)

But in higher levels the meaning may change substantially. In this example you are saying the opposite when you replace subjunctive by indicative:

- "no se marcha porque **esté** cansado" = "the reason he is not leaving is not because he is tired"
- "no se marcha porque **está** cansado" = "he is not leaving because he is tired"

BTW, online translators fail miserably with that example.

B1 examples:

> Ojalá que tengas suerte.
> Quizá / tal vez vaya.
> Quiero que vengas.
> Dice que me siente.
> Es bueno que estudies.
> Me voy antes de que llueva.
> Llámame después de que hablen con él.
> Te lo doy para que lo uses.

B2 examples:

> Que te vayas.
> Busco un libro que sea divertido.
> Voy donde me digas.
> Lo haré como digas.
> Quien tenga mi cartera que me la devuelva.
> No es cierto que lo sepa.
> No creo que estés bien.
> Una vez que hayamos estudiado el problema, decidiremos.
> Apenas sepa algo, te lo comunico.
> Me quedo hasta que termines.
> Aunque me lo pidas de rodillas, no lo haré.
> A pesar de que pueda ser una mentira, prefiero creerle.
> He venido a que me solucionen el problema.
> Tal vez fuera ella.
> Quisiera ver ese abrigo.
> Dijo que fuera.
> No es verdad que haya escrito esa carta.
> Cuando se haya marchado / se marche, avisamos a sus padres.

C1 examples:

> Así te lleves un buen susto.
> ¡Que te calles de una vez, hombre!
> No veo que tengas motivos.
> No ve que hay / haya un letrero ahí.
> No niega que sea él.
> No se marcha porque esté cansado.
> Así tuviera que volver a hacerlo.
> Quién tuviera tus años.
> Pienso que se habrá quedado dormido. / No pienso que se haya quedado dormido.

C2 examples:

> Dondequiera que mires sólo encuentras miseria.
> ¿Es que / acaso lo niegas porque esté él?
> ¿Acaso / es que no lo niegas porque esté él?
> No se tira al agua así lo maten.
> Porque grites más no tienes razón.
> Por más que te disculpes, no te pienso perdonar.
> A riesgo de que me echen, me negaré.
> Entiendo que ante una reacción así te hayas marchado.
> No creo que una persona como él haya pasado / pasase sin darse cuenta.
> A quien correspondiere.
> Si procediere.
> Sea como fuere.
> Donde fueres haz lo que vieres.